# Pandas dataframe - drop function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

```
index 
"#" 
"Name", "Type 1", "Type 2",  "Total", "HP", "Attack", "Defense Sp.",  "Atk Sp.",
"Def",  
"Speed" 
"Generation"    
"Legendary"
```

I have a dataset on pokemon with the above mentioned columns. When getting the shape of the data I get (800,12). But I have 14 columns in total.

1. Why is it like that?
2. How to drop the "#" column as drop function is not working for it.

I tried with this code:

```
df_pk = df_pk.drop("#", axis = 1)
```

Comment: What is the output of `print(df_pk.columns)` ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [ ]
list(df_pk.columns)

['#',
 'Name',
 'Type 1',
 'Type 2',
 'Total',
 'HP',
 'Attack',
 'Defense',
 'Sp. Atk',
 'Sp. Def',
 'Speed',
 'Generation',
 'Legendary']    This is the output. I get "#' in this list, but not able to drop it .....i get the error -

Comment: KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-f34725344b0d> in <module>
----> 1 df_pk1 = df_pk.drop("#", axis = 1)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in drop(self, labels, errors)
   6015         if mask.any():
   6016             if errors != "ignore":
-> 6017                 raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask]} not found in axis")
   6018             indexer = indexer[~mask]
   6019         return self.delete(indexer)

KeyError: "['#'] not found in axis"

Comment: please update the question with the results of printing columns and your error message, don't put it in comments.